# Calling one of many possible instance methods based on user input

Tags: python

I'm making a script which calls methods based on user input. Let's say I have a list of instances `instances = [MyClass(), MyClass()]`, and instance methods `foo()` and `bar()` in `MyClass` I would like to call. The user input should be two integers separated by whitespace, which are then stored as `instance` and `method`. When the user inputs `1 0`, I would like the 1st instance to call the 0th method (`foo()`, the numbering of the methods is arbitrary, in this example I chose 0 for foo and 1 for bar).
Choosing the right instance is trivial, `instances[instance]`, but I also need to call a method of this instance without knowing which method it is beforehand, so using the usual dot notation is out of the question, and I would like to avoid using exec().

I've considered two approaches. The first one is `getattr()`. I could use a dict or list like `methods = ['foo', 'bar']`, and call:

```
getattr(instances[instance], methods[method])()
```

(or even just have the user input the method name outright).

The other approach is one I came up with - I can store references to the methods in a list, like this:
`methods = [MyClass.foo, MyClass.bar]`,
and treat them kind of like a class method:

```
methods[method](instances[instance])
```

I was surprised to see this actually works, as I couldn't find anything online about it. It makes sense, I'm calling the method and passing `self` to it, instead of `self` being automatically passed to it when it's called from an instance, but I wonder if the behaviour is different when doing that.

My question is, which is the more pythonic approach (and are there other ones I haven't considered)? And does the second approach somehow differ from calling the method from an instance? Answers about a better way to accomplish 'user input -> specific instance calls a specific method' are also welcome.

Comment: I think that most of us would need to see some code to really understand what you are up to.  @staticmethod allows you to define a class with no args, just to get data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `getattr()` approach so the code will work properly for instances of a subclass that overrides the methods. If you put `Classname.methodname` in the list, you'll always call the base class method, not the method of the subclass.